# Issues with spaces in file path in GRASS r.in.lidar function

Tags: grass-gis, lidar

Am using the r.in.lidar function in GRASS to manipulate multiple lidar files within GRASS.

For testing purposes i did everything with one file only by using the following line and this worked.

```
r.in.lidar -e -n -o --o output=Rst_Min_cf2  input="C:\Users\XXX\OneDrive - XXX\Projects\XXX\XXX_1K_Las.laz" method=min resolution=5 class_filter=2
```

However, i have more than 20 files that i would like to analyse together as file by file would be a bit cumbersome.

r.in.lidar allows the user to send a list of files to analyse together and i have successfully used that in the past. I tried to do the same in this case with the following line

```
r.in.lidar -e -n -o --overwrite output=Lidar file="C:\Users\XXX\OneDrive - XXX\Projects\XXX\AllLidarFiles.txt" method=min resolution=5 zrange=-1,100 class_filter=2
```

However, it did not work and i got

**ERROR: Input file XXXX does not exist**

After trying many thinks, i moved all my files to another folder making sure there were no spaces in the path

```
r.in.lidar -e -n -o -p --overwrite output=Lidar file=C:\Users\XXX\Desktop\XXX\AllLidarFiles.txt method=min resolution=5 zrange=-1,100 class_filter=2
```

and this did work, which made me think that the issue arises because of the spaces in the file path.

Does anyone know exactly why this problem occurs and how i could solve it without moving all my files to a folder whose path does not have any spaces at all?

Comment: Can you try with `file=C:\Users\XXX\OneDrive^ -^ XXX\Projects\XXX\AllLidarFiles.txt` ?

Comment: put quotes around your path with spaces like "C:\path with\spaces\file.las" when using command line instructions. Eventually you may assimilate like us old DOS users and use paths without spaces, made of all alphanumeric characters - we've been bitten by the surprise *space* or *punctuation* in file path too many times. To get a file list of all your LAS files use **DIR /B /S "C:\Users\XXX\OneDrive - XXX\Projects\XXX\XXX_1K_Las\\*.LAS" > YourTextFile.txt** and use the text file as your input - old CMD users trick.

Comment: Thanks for your comments. The ^ did not work, but i ended up finding a solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After trying many things i was able to find a solution. I used the same line i had tried before

```
r.in.lidar -e -n -o --overwrite output=Lidar file="C:\Users\XXX\OneDrive - XXX\Projects\XXX\AllLidarFiles.txt" method=min resolution=5 zrange=-1,100 class_filter=2
```

However, within the text file AllLidarFiles.txt files did not have to have quotes.

**This is what i had before in the text file, and this was not working**

```
"C:\Users\XXX\OneDrive - XXX\XXX\XXX_2011_608000_7412000_1K_Las.las"
"C:\Users\XXX\OneDrive - XXX\XXX\XXX_2011_608000_7413000_1K_Las.las"
"C:\Users\XXX\OneDrive - XXX\XXX\XXX_2011_609000_7412000_1K_Las.las"
"C:\Users\XXX\OneDrive - XXX\XXX\XXX_2011_609000_7413000_1K_Las.las"
```

**This is what i have now in AllLidarFiles.txt and is working.**

```
C:\Users\XXX\OneDrive - XXX\XXX\XXX_2011_608000_7412000_1K_Las.las
C:\Users\XXX\OneDrive - XXX\XXX\XXX_2011_608000_7413000_1K_Las.las
C:\Users\XXX\OneDrive - XXX\XXX\XXX_2011_609000_7412000_1K_Las.las
C:\Users\XXX\OneDrive - XXX\XXX\XXX_2011_609000_7413000_1K_Las.las
```